# More efficient way to collect all DLL in a project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019, directx-11, directxtk

I want export a executable file to others and they can play the game with a click, but when I click the executable file it immediately shutdown. I think it missed some DLL file to be able to run. So I checked the build log.

```
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'.
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d11.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\D3DCompiler_47.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll'. 
'Pacman.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll'.
```

.......and so on.

Is there only one way that manually copies all files mentioned above?

[Project Link](https://github.com/tucna/Pac-T-Man)

Comment: See [Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=vs-2019) for a starting point.

Comment: If it does not even run on the computer that it was built on, it won't run anywhere else. You need to fix the bugs first.

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of those files are just part of the Windows operating system.

`msvcp140.dll` is part of the Visual C++ Runtime. You can deploy these side-by-side (i.e. xcopy style deployment). See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/deployment-in-visual-cpp). Exactly which files you need depends on which version if Visual C++ you are using to build the game.

- **vcruntime140.dll**
- **msvcp140.dll**
- **concrt140.dll** (only used for Windows XP)
- **vccorlib140.dll** (only used for C++/CX)
- **msvcp140_1.dll**: (added in VS 2017) C++17 memory_resource
- **msvcp140_2.dll**: (added in VS 2017 15.7) C++17 mathematical special functions
- **vcruntime140_1.dll**: (added in VS 2019) __CxxFrameHandler4 for FH4 (x64 only)
- **msvcp140_codecvt_ids.dll**: (added in VS 2019 16.2) fixes for codecvt for `char8_t`, `char16_t`, and `char32_t`.

The `D3DCompiler_47.dll` HLSL compiler depends on your minimum operating system. Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 already include it. If you need to support Windows 7 SP1 or Windows 8.0, you can include it side-by-side with your game. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/).